# swift 4.0 dispatch_semaphore_wait with DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore, swift4

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(writeSemaphore!, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

gives error  for DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER i.e.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'dispatch_time_t' (aka 'UInt64')
```

Een assigning a value **DispatchTime.distantFuture** could not help.

Can any one let me know what could be the value of **dispatch_time_t**(timeout)

Comment: `dispatch_semaphore_wait` is a Swift 2 API. Use `DispatchSemaphore` in Swift 3 and later.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go for:

```
    writeSemaphore!.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
```

But you should improve you code, by making sure your optional isn't nil. Go for a guard as follows:

```
    guard let writeSemaphore = writeSemaphore else { return }

    writeSemaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
```